# How to define Stage in FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I want to define my GUI entirely in FXML. I started with JavaFX templates that are shown everywhere from Oracle docs to Netbeans templates.
In these templates there is no Stage defined in FXML, just the actual Scene with UI controlls in it. Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fxskuska.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

That seemed okay, until the first thing I wanted to change - to set the window's name. That's when I realized Scene is not a Window (or a JFrame analogy), but Stage is.
When I tried to wrap all this inside a  element, I couldn't set the `fx:controller` attribute to the AnchorPane, because it is not a root element anymore. I even tried to "outsource" it by using `fx:include` in the Stage file, but that just gave me an "Unexpected closing tag:scene" error.

1. How to define Stage in FXML?
2. Is Stage the JFX analogy of JFrame?

Comment: *"I couldn't set the fx:controller attribute to the AnchorPane, because it is not a root element anymore."* Why don't you just move the attribute to the root element?

Comment: Can't move it to the root, because the root (Stage) does not have a controller property.

Comment: You're not setting it as a property on the element, it just defines the class that the `FXMLLoader` uses to create the controller. `AnchorPane` doesn't have a controller property either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FXML essentially just defines ways to create objects (typically via a no-arg constructor) and call `setXXX` methods on those objects. See ["Class instance elements"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#class_instance_elements) and ["Property elements"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#property_elements) in the documentation. So you can readily implement

```
new Scene()
```

with

```xml
<Scene>...</Scene>
```

and

```
new Stage()
```

with

```xml
<Stage>...</Stage>
```

and

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
Scene scene = new Scene();
scene.setRoot(new AnchorPane(...));
stage.setScene(scene);
```

with

```xml
<Stage>
    <scene>
        <Scene>
            <root>
                <AnchorPane ><!--...--></AnchorPane>
            </root>
        </Scene>
    </scene>
<Stage>
```

The `fx:controller` attribute *must* go in the root element, as should the namespace info.

So:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<?import javafx.stage.Stage ?>

<Stage title="My Application" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="FXMLDocumentController">

    <scene>

        <Scene>

            <root>

                <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320">
                    <children>
                        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!"
                            onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
                        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69"
                            fx:id="label" />
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>

            </root>
        </Scene>

    </scene>

</Stage>
```

and then you would load this with

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXMLStageTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Stage stage = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Stage.fxml"));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you want the controller specifically to apply to the pane, you can use one FXML file for the `Stage` and `Scene`, and then use [`fx:include` elements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements) for the other piece(s). That way you can split the UI into several FXML-controller pairs. It feels a bit redundant to use an FXML file just for a `Stage` (you may as well do this part in Java, surely), but it is possible:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.stage.Stage ?>

<Stage title="My Application" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <scene>
        <Scene>
            <root>
                <fx:include source="RootPane.fxml"/>
            </root>
        </Scene>
    </scene>
</Stage>
```

and then your original FXML file is `RootPane.fxml`. You could similarly decompose that with further `fx:include` tags if you needed.

Comment: But what if I want a Stage with 2 or more Scenes, each with its own controller? If I set the fx:controller in the root element (Stage), wouldn't that force me to use the controller on all scenes?

Comment: @Leprechaun You cannot set more than one `Scene` in a single `Stage` and you cannot replace the `Scene` of a `Stage` with fxml alone. Forget about "programming" anything in fxml. You're defining the structure there. For more complicated things you still have to use java code.

Comment: @Leprechaun You can have multiple FXML files combined with `fx:include` elements. See update. But it sounds a bit as though you haven't really understood the whole concept of FXML and controllers. I recommend you research and experiment a bit more.

Comment: @James_D Well I still kinda do have to use the fx:include thingy if I want to use the SceneBuilder, just because it can't open Stages.

Comment: @Leprechaun So why not just do the usual thing and define your `Stage` in Java?

Comment: @James_D It seems confusing and untidy to have one part of UI structure and attributes defined in xml and the other part in code. Either do one thing or the other. Just seems like a bad practice

Comment: The `Stage` is not part of the structure. It's a window, i.e. a container for the structure. It's specific to the application that uses it. The structure represented by FXML is reusable; can be used directly in a `Scene` or can be part of a larger structure.

Comment: Alright then, I should get used to it. Thanks a lot @James_D , fabian